# Visual Studio Code setting delete empty line

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I delete red box empty line? When scrollbar touch bottom, empty line will appear, I want to delete these empty line.

[image: delete red box empty line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are technically not lines (see they don't have line number), but a generated visual space below the last line of your file.

You can turn off this feature by adding the following to your [preferences](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) (File > Preferences Settings):

```
"editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false,
```

By doing this, the last line of your file will be at the bottom of the editor pane when you scroll down to the maximum.